# MYSQL if a status is liked by a user include it in query results

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, conditional-statements

I am returning a array of user created statuses in a feed. I have realized that looping through the mysql results in php post mysql to add on additional key/values ridiculously slows down our api response times so im trying to eliminate any foreach looping in php on this array of statuses.

here is my table setup:

**USERS TABLE** 
UID / FIRST_NAME/ LAST_NAME/ECT

**UPDATES TABLE**
msg_id/message/ UID_FK

**LIKED  TABLE**
LIKED_ID/ MSG_ID_FK/ LIKED_BY_UID

Is there a way that in mysql i can include a  "isLiked" bool  if the user making the api request has liked the update on each row returned in my query?

Here is my actual query im working with, it has a bit more data than i described in it but the goal is the same....find a way to add a 'isLiked' column to each row:

```
SELECT b.type,b.owner,b.update_img,b.ALBUM_ID,b.last_comment,a.uid, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.gender, a.thumb_img, b.msg_id, b.message, b.created,b.POST_PRIVACY
                FROM users AS a, updates AS b, LIKED as c WHERE b.uid_fk = a.uid AND b.type<>'FRIEND_RELATIONSHIP'AND b.created<$time  AND b.type<>'FAMILIAR_RELATIONSHIP' AND a.college='$college' AND b.POST_PRIVACY<>'4' AND b.POST_PRIVACY<>'5' AND b.created>=$tstamp ORDER BY b.created DESC
                LIMIT 100
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a version of the query where I attempt to do what im aiming for ,but the problem is this ONLY returns the rows that I have liked:

```
SELECT b.type, b.owner, b.update_img, b.ALBUM_ID, b.last_comment, a.uid, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.gender, a.thumb_img, b.msg_id, b.message, b.created, b.POST_PRIVACY,c.LIKED
FROM users AS a, updates AS b, LIKES AS c
WHERE b.uid_fk = a.uid
AND b.POST_PRIVACY <> '4'
AND b.POST_PRIVACY <> '5'
AND c.LIKED_UID = '1'
AND b.msg_id = c.MSG_ID_FK
ORDER BY b.created DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting only the line with liked but want all the lines, try this:

```
SELECT b.type, b.owner, b.update_img, b.ALBUM_ID, b.last_comment, a.uid, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.gender, a.thumb_img, b.msg_id, b.message, b.created, b.POST_PRIVACY,c.LIKED
FROM users AS a, updates AS b, BUMPS AS c
WHERE b.uid_fk = a.uid
AND b.POST_PRIVACY <> '4'
AND b.POST_PRIVACY <> '5'
AND ((c.LIKED_UID = '1'
AND b.msg_id = c.MSG_ID_FK)
OR c.MSG_ID_FK IS NULL
)
ORDER BY b.created DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Added null test so that it is equivalent to a `LEFT JOIN`.

The column `c.LIKED` will be 1 when there is a liked on that message id and `null` when it doesn't.

**-- EDIT --**

As the above didn't work (may be wrong, I didn't test it), try this form of writing it (I like this way):

```
SELECT b.type, b.owner, b.update_img, b.ALBUM_ID, b.last_comment, a.uid, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.gender, a.thumb_img, b.msg_id, b.message, b.created, b.POST_PRIVACY,c.LIKED
FROM 
  users AS a
  INNER JOIN updates AS b ON b.uid_fk = a.uid
  LEFT JOIN BUMPS AS c ON b.msg_id = c.MSG_ID_FK
WHERE b.POST_PRIVACY <> '4'
AND b.POST_PRIVACY <> '5'
ORDER BY b.created DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Note that it will only select lines that are related on users and updates, and values from table BUMPS will be selected as NULL if no related line exists. This is what I recommend.

(deleted informations that could cause error and lead to confusion)

**-- EDIT 2 added a test-case with simplified data and query --**
I didn't see the entire problem before, then I did a test-case.

I created test tables and data:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test_multi_sets`()
    DETERMINISTIC
begin
        select user() as first_col;
        select user() as first_col, now() as second_col;
        select user() as first_col, now() as second_col, now() as third_col;
        end$$

DELIMITER ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BUMPS` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `MSG_ID_FK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LIKED_UID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LIKED` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `BUMPS` (`id`, `MSG_ID_FK`, `LIKED_UID`, `LIKED`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1),
(2, 3, 2, 0),
(3, 1, 2, 0);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `updates` (
`msg_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uid_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `POST_PRIVACY` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `updates` (`msg_id`, `uid_fk`, `text`, `POST_PRIVACY`) VALUES
(1, 1, 't11', 3),
(2, 1, 't12', 3),
(3, 2, 't21', 3),
(4, 2, 't22', 3);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`uid`, `name`, `pass`) VALUES
(1, 'u1', 'p1'),
(2, 'u2', 'p2');


ALTER TABLE `BUMPS`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `MSG_ID_FK` (`MSG_ID_FK`), ADD KEY `LIKED_UID` (`LIKED_UID`);

ALTER TABLE `updates`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`msg_id`), ADD KEY `uid_fk` (`uid_fk`);

ALTER TABLE `users`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`uid`);


ALTER TABLE `BUMPS`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
ALTER TABLE `updates`
MODIFY `msg_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=5;
ALTER TABLE `users`
MODIFY `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

ALTER TABLE `BUMPS`
ADD CONSTRAINT `bumps_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`LIKED_UID`) REFERENCES `users` (`uid`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `bumps_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`MSG_ID_FK`) REFERENCES `updates` (`msg_id`);

ALTER TABLE `updates`
ADD CONSTRAINT `updates_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`uid_fk`) REFERENCES `users` (`uid`);
```

and run this select:

```
SELECT a.uid, a.name, b.msg_id, b.text, b.POST_PRIVACY, c.LIKED
FROM users AS a
  INNER JOIN updates AS b ON b.uid_fk = a.uid
  LEFT JOIN BUMPS AS c ON (c.LIKED_UID = 1 AND b.msg_id = c.MSG_ID_FK)
WHERE NOT (b.POST_PRIVACY IN(4, 5)) LIMIT 100
```

with these results:

```
 | uid | name | msg_id | text | POST_PRIVACY | LIKED
 | 1   | u1   | 1      | t11  | 3            | 1
 | 1   | u1   | 2      | t12  | 3            | NULL
 | 2   | u2   | 3      | t21  | 3            | NULL
 | 2   | u2   | 4      | t22  | 3            | NULL
```

Even that user 2 liked updates, it won't show on user1 query.

I hope this helps you to solve your problem. I believe that I can't go any further than this, but anyway, send a message if needed.

Caution if using this on your production server, as first scrip on the EDIT 2 will create tables.

Comment: This still seems to be returning ONLY the rows that I have liked and not including any rows that I have not liked. 


Its hard to tell if im explaining this right or not, but essentially the problem is  that a status being "liked"  is a 1 to many relationship .  a status can be liked by several users or no users ( in which case their will be no way to connect to the 'LIKED'  table )   thats the hang up im stuck on .

Comment: It should not... It isn't a complex query, I ll give it some more time and update.

Comment: idk if this helps any but here is a thread i created where i tried to word what im aiming for better:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769884/mysql-select-subquery-if-exists/31769978?noredirect=1#comment51471292_31769978

Comment: @ChuckKelly Ok, added a testcase. Mysql doesn't like comments with --, so it was an error on my part to put them, the query would not work as intended anyway, now it should be close than what you want, you only need to add/modify fields on the select.

Comment: You are welcome and I am happy to have helped and with the correct answer mark :-)